# Get the value from hashtable using index

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have hashtable in my application which is build on VS with C#, but I get null value by using indexer. If I use the RuntimeHelpers, I can get the value. Why I can not used index?

There is my code using index:

```
 dtmLastModified = Conversions.ToDate(hashTable[filepath]);
```

I can get the value from below code:

```
  dtmLastModified=Conversions.ToDate(hashTable[RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(filepath).ToString().ToLower()]);
```

Comment: What type is *hashTable*?

Comment: Also, there is no reason to use the Visual Basic compiler helpers in a c# application. They're meant to be used internally by the VB compiler only.

Comment: Breakpoint. Immediate window. Done.